# How to send some amount to a Contract in truffle

Tags: truffle, testrpc

My contracts were tested in both Browser Solidity and Mist Wallet and it works fine. I am trying to use testrpc and trying to depoy

Below is the javascript I am using it on truffle console

contribute - is a function which will accept address and it is of payable type. "0xe014b7528ae8b245b829dca3f9abceabc777b387" is the contract address

Please let me know what could be wrong here.

```
truffle(development)> hub.then(function(instance){
return instance.contribute("0xe014b7528ae8b245b829dca3f9abceabc777b387",{
from:web3.eth.accounts[0],value:10
});
}).then(function(result) {console.log(result)});
```

Comment: It's a little different between truffle 2 and 3. Which one are we talking about?

Comment: I am developing using truffle 3

Answer (score 4):

First, use the migrations script in ./migrations, usually 2_deploy_contracts.js.

Comment out the MetaCoin example and ...

```
artifacts ... path to your source file
deployer.deploy(YourContractName);
```

Back to linux shell, root dir of your project.

```
$ truffle migrate
```

...

The foregoing just gets truffle situated to help you out. In particular, it knows the contract address and function abstractions.

```
$ truffle console
> var contract = ContractName.deployed();
> contract.contribute({value: 1}); 
> contract.balance
```

I'm hoping the simplified syntax helps you out. I imagine it should work okay because you're pausing between each step.

Use `.then(function(result) {})` to start working with "thenable" responses in scripts that don't wait around for the user to type something.

Comment: I tried for sometime and now able to send funds. Have attached few screen shots and code. Thank you Rob !!

Comment: Great. Polly worth a bump if it helped. The results are BigNumbers, so more fun ahead. Try contract.balance.toString(10);

Answer (score 2):

I have added step by step instructions as suggested. I hope it would help someone

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

import "./B.sol";

contract A {

   address[] public addElements;

   function A() payable {

   }

   function create(string x,string y) returns (address a) {
       B obj = new B(x,y);
       addElements.push(obj);
       return obj;
   }

   function contribute(address x) payable returns (bool) {

    if(msg.value == 0) return false;

    address contributor = msg.sender;

    bool isFailure = B(x).donate.value(msg.value)(contributor);

    return isFailure;

   }


   function getElements() returns (address[] ) {
       return addElements;
   }

}

pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract B {

     struct details  {
        string name;
        string desc;
    } 

   details public param;

   function B(string a,string b) {
       param.name = a;
       param.desc = b;
   }

   function donate(address x) payable returns (bool) {

    // TODO functionality to be added
    return true;

   }

   function getInfo () constant returns (string name, string desc) {
        return (param.name,param.desc);
   }

}
```

[image: screen shot 1]
[image: screen shot 2]